# $("button").trigger("click") does not seem to be working properly

Tags: jquery, post, hyperlink

I recently made a program called "Mathquiz".  Basically the program asks two questions, and when the submit button is clicked, it displays how many you got correct and adds your score to a database, identifying you by your e-mail.  I tried to add an additional functionality, a timer: when the time runs out, it's supposed to act as if the submit button has been clicked.

However, when I run the code, it doesn't work.  The address bar reads "http://localhost:3000/?q1=correct&q2=wrong" and it does not go to the other page it is supposed to.

Here is the code:

```
    <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/momentjs/2.12.0/moment.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body onload = "timer();">
<span id = "timer">0:00</span>
<br>
E-mail: <input type="text" id = "email"> <span id = "emCheck" style = "color:red;">Please enter valid e-mail address.</span>
<br>
<br>
<!-- <form action = "result.html"> -->
  <!-- so the question is how do we get it to link to another page -->
  <form>
  <ol>
  <li>  
  <p>What is 2 + 2?</p>
  <input type="radio" name="q1" value="correct">4<br>
  <input type="radio" name="q1" value="wrong">8<br>
  <input type="radio" name="q1" value="wrong">6
</li>
<br>
<li>
  <p>What is 2 + 6?</p>
  <input type="radio" name="q2" value="correct">8<br>
  <input type="radio" name="q2" value="wrong">14<br>
  <input type="radio" name="q2" value="wrong">3
</li>
  </ol>
  <button onclick = "check();"><a href = "api/result">submit</a></button>
</form>
<!-- <script src="script.js"></script> -->
<script>
  time = 120;

function countDown(){
  time--;

  minutes = Math.floor(time/60);
  seconds = time%60;
  opZero = "";
  //must figure out how to make turn into a zero when seconds
  //becomes single digit

  $("#timer").text(minutes + ":" + opZero + seconds);
  //still need to figure out how to format time

  //When it reaches zero, same function as clicking submit.

  if (seconds < 10)
  {
    opZero = "0";
  }
  //this doesn't work.  Why!?


  if (time == 0)
  {
    $("button").trigger("click");
    // $("a").trigger("click");
    //why isn't this working?
    //the url even changes but the page does not.
  }
}

  function timer(){
    setInterval(countDown, 1000)
  }
// var q1int1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1;
// var q1int2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1;
var numCorrect = 0;
var userID = "";
var atSign = "@";
var dot = ".";
document.onkeyup = function(event)
{
    userID = $("#email").val();
    if (userID.includes(atSign) == true  && userID.includes(dot) == true)
    {
        $("#emCheck").text("Thank you for your email address!");
        $("#emCheck").css("color", "black");
    }
    else
    {
        $("#emCheck").text("Please enter a valid email.");
    }
//check e-mail for @ sign and .
}

function c(input)
{
if (input == "correct")
{
    numCorrect++;
}

}




function check()
{
var q1Answer = $("input[name='q1']:checked").val();
c(q1Answer);
var q2Answer = $("input[name='q2']:checked").val();
c(q2Answer);
var userID = $("#email").val();
var time = moment().format('MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a');

console.log("Time:" + time);
console.log("Answers:" + q1Answer + q2Answer);
console.log("Score:" + numCorrect);
console.log("email:" + userID);

//store num correct in local storage
localStorage.setItem("numCorrect", numCorrect);

var newItem = {email: userID,
                score: numCorrect,
        time: time}


      $.post("/api/new", newItem)
      .then(function(data) {
        console.log("newItem is:" + data);
        //those one does not show up
        alert("Adding task...");
      });

}

// function start()
// {
//  // $("#q1int1").text(q1int1);
//  // $("#q1int2").text(q1int2);

// }

</script>
</body>
```

Why is this?  I've tried putting a ".trigger" on the link, but this only makes things worse.

Comment: Why do you have a link inside your button? This is not semantically correct. And when you state "it does not go to the page it is supposed to" are you referring to this link inside the button?

Comment: Yes I am, when you click submit the url reads "http://localhost:3000/api/result" and displays the document "result.html"

Comment: Sorry, I can't make sense of that. Either the URL is api/result or result.html unless the api/result is rendering the contents of result.html?

Comment: The latter is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Consider changing the way you handle your form "check" and submission using a `submit` event handler.

When the form is submitted you can invoke `check()`. When the countdown reaches 0 you are simply triggering the submit event – who's handler subsequently invokes `check()` and redirects the user using `location.href`.

First, modify your check function so it returns `$.post` because you'll want to make sure the request is complete before navigating away from the page. We'll demonstrate that later.

```
function check() {
  ...
  return $.post("/api/new", ...);
}
```

In your countdown function you'll want to trigger the submit event when the countdown ends so you'll want to replace `$("button").trigger("click")` with `$("form").submit()`

Change your button to a standard submit button. This will submit the form natively and will fire your submit handler.

```
<button type="submit">submit</button>
```

Bind a submit handler that invokes `check()` and then once the `$.post` in that function completes it will send the user to the next page.

```
$("form").submit(function (event) {
  // prevents the default form behaviour
  event.preventDefault();
  // disable the submit button to prevent repeated submissions
  $(":submit", this).prop("disabled", true);
  // 'check' now returns $.post (Promise) therefore you can chain .then()
  check().then(function() {
    // redirect to the desired page
    window.location.href = "/api/result";
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding ID to button element and reference it by ID in jquery selector, perhaps jquery doesnt really